# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ExtensionError Message: Operation: Read; Exception: [A task was canceled.]

Tags: c#

I am using the following example for Microsoft Graph Webhook
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample
It was working fine till yesterday, but now i am getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ExtensionError  Message: Operation: Read; Exception: [A task was canceled.]    Inner error       at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__19.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__36.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__32`1.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at Microsoft.Graph.SubscriptionRequest.d__6.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at ---------------------------------------------------

Any one faced similar kind of problem to get email notification or create subscription using Microsoft.Graph API
Even i reconfigured application in
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

and give the following permissions in "Microsoft Graph Permissions" section,
Delegated Permissions:
**Mail.Read**
**User.Read**

Application Permissions:
**Mail.Read (Admin only)**
**User.Read.All(Admin only)**

and even now while creating subscription i am also getting same kind of error:

while creating subscription token is created and webhook listen the request but when i return response back to Microsoft Graph then i am getting following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ExtensionError  Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [A task was canceled.]
>
> token:YTQyYTY5YzctYjg0Ny00Zjg0LWFiMWItMTQ1OGRkYmY2M2Q2

I am using following code to create subscription:
// The `notificationUrl` endpoint that's registered with the webhook subscription.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()
{

    // Validate the new subscription by sending the token back to Microsoft Graph.
    // This response is required for each subscription.
    if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)
    {
        var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
        return Content(token, "plain/text");
    }

    // Parse the received notifications.
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var notifications = new Dictionary<string, Notification>();
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(inputStream.ReadToEnd());
                if (jsonObject != null)
                {

                    // Notifications are sent in a 'value' array. The array might contain multiple notifications for events that are
                    // registered for the same notification endpoint, and that occur within a short timespan.
                    JArray value = JArray.Parse(jsonObject["value"].ToString());
                    foreach (var notification in value)
                    {
                        var current = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(notification.ToString());

                        // Check client state to verify the message is from Microsoft Graph.
                        var subscription = SubscriptionCache.GetSubscriptionCache().GetSubscriptionInfo(current.SubscriptionId);

                        // This sample only works with subscriptions that are still cached.
                        if (subscription != null)
                        {
                            if (current.ClientState == subscription.ClientState)
                            {
                                // Just keep the latest notification for each resource.
                                // No point pulling data more than once.
                                notifications[current.Resource] = current;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (notifications.Count > 0)
                    {

                        // Query for the changed messages.
                        await GetChangedMessagesAsync(notifications.Values);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Handle the exception.
            // Still return a 202 so the service doesn't resend the notification.
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(202);
    }
}
```